# Start azure project from command line

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2017

We have an ASP .Net (not CORE) project. There is a different Azure project as startup that starts the Azure emulator and then the website via IISExpress. I want to write some UI tests against the website. How do I start the Azure project from the command line?

Also, I've tried launching the website directly with IISExpress in the command line and getting an error; so I'm trying to take the approach of launching the Azure project from the command line instead.

Comment: Did you deploy your web to Azure? If yes, you could just go to browser the site why you want to launch it with command line. Or you want to start the Azure web?

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the ASP.NET Application using command line via IISExpress, you can use the below command and start IISExpress and then invoke the web request with specific URL and port. And if you are trying to publish the web app to azure , then try to invoke the web request with the Azure Web App URL.

[image]

Hope above information helps.